# Configure a default shell script environment

Tags: shell, sh

Is there any way to change the default environment when running `sh -c <command>`?
It appears that .cshrc is not called when running command with a -c flag.

Comment: Does this help?http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-311573/

Comment: Why do you expect csh to be called when you run `sh -c`?